# Checking status of Backup in github enterprise without root priviledge?

Tags: linux, github, github-enterprise

Well, I have established a GitHub enterprise environment in my linux environment. Somehow, I am not able to get root access. So in process of upgrading GitHub, I want to get information about the running status of my GitHub environment. Is it possible, to check the running status without having root access?

Comment: GitHub Enterprise runs on an appliance.  If you are able to login to the admin console on the proper port as admin, you will have ability to sudo as root (unless your site has major messed with the appliance of course, in which case you would have to ask them)
So I guess I am asking are you trying to check the status outside the appliance ?  from the BUS (Backup Utility Server) ?  all of that will make a difference

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the directory tree where the backups are being written to.  There is a file "in-progress" that is removed at the end of a backup. Also the directory link "current" is moved to that most recent backup if the backups were successful, otherwise "current" stays where it was.

We have wrapper scripts we use around our backups to log it and capture the exit status